# How can I see the structure of this array?

Tags: php, echo

How can I see the structure of the array stored in `$response`? I've tried `print_r()` but I can't see anything in the chrome developer (got the php console) .

```
 function myajax_inputtitleSubmit_func() {

     global $wpdb;
$mp_country_table_info = $wpdb->prefix . 'countries '; //Good practice
$mpcountrys = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT labour_cost FROM $mp_country_table_info WHERE id='2' ");


        $nonce = $_POST['nextNonce'];   
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-next-nonce' ) )
        die ( 'Busted!');

    $numwelds = isset($_POST['numberofwelds']) ? $_POST['numberofwelds'] : '';
$numconwelds = isset($_POST['numberofconwelds']) ? $_POST['numberofconwelds'] : '';
$fortot2 = 5;
$fortot3 = 2;

if (is_numeric($numwelds) && is_numeric($numconwelds))
{
    $total['tot1'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $mpcountrys ;
    $total['tot2'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $fortot2 ;
    $total['tot3'] = ($numwelds + $numconwelds) + $fortot2 / $fortot3; 
    $response = json_encode($total);
    print_r($total); // added line
    header("Content-Type: application/json");  
    echo $response;
    exit;
}
```

**UPDATE**  I've tried the following & it didn't work:

```
   $total['tot1'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $mpcountrys ;
    $total['tot2'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $fortot2 ;
    $total['tot3'] = ($numwelds + $numconwelds) + $fortot2 / $fortot3; 
    $response = json_encode($total);
    header("Content-Type: application/json");  
    echo $response;
    exit;
    //added bit
    echo '<pre>';
    echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '</pre>';
```

**UPDATE TWO This doesn't seem to work either:**

```
       $total['tot1'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $mpcountrys ;
    $total['tot2'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $fortot2 ;
    $total['tot3'] = ($numwelds + $numconwelds) + $fortot2 / $fortot3; 
    echo '<pre>';
    echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '</pre>';
    header("Content-Type: application/json");  
    echo $response;
    exit;
```

This is the first time I've tried to use the chrome php console. I've 'added' it . I've also made sure I've got it working properly, by looking at this site http://php-console.com/instance/examples/#debug_vars .

**Update three - all the full function**

```
 function myajax_inputtitleSubmit_func() {

 global $wpdb;
$mp_country_table_info = $wpdb->prefix . 'countries '; //Good practice
$mpcountrys = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT labour_cost FROM $mp_country_table_info WHERE id='2' ");


        $nonce = $_POST['nextNonce'];   
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-next-nonce' ) )
        die ( 'Busted!');

    $numwelds = isset($_POST['numberofwelds']) ? $_POST['numberofwelds'] : '';
$numconwelds = isset($_POST['numberofconwelds']) ? $_POST['numberofconwelds'] : '';
$fortot2 = 5;
$fortot3 = 2;

if (is_numeric($numwelds) && is_numeric($numconwelds))
{
    $total['tot1'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $mpcountrys ;
    $total['tot2'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $fortot2 ;
    $total['tot3'] = ($numwelds + $numconwelds) + $fortot2 / $fortot3; 
    echo '<pre>';
    echo json_encode($total, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '</pre>';
    header("Content-Type: application/json");  
    echo $response;
   // exit;
} 
}
```

**Update 4 - try var_dump  - also didn't work**

```
$total['tot1'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $mpcountrys ;
$total['tot2'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $fortot2 ;
$total['tot3'] = ($numwelds + $numconwelds) + $fortot2 / $fortot3; 
$response = json_encode($total);
header("Content-Type: application/json");  
echo $response;
exit;
echo  '<pre>';
var_dump($response);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: remove `exit;` or move it after all your print statements

Comment: @ponciste Thanks, I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: sorry, you have to do `echo json_encode($total, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Comment: @ponciste Thanks, I've also tried `echo json_encode($total, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` & that doesn't seem to work

Comment: that's really weird...

Comment: @ponciste I've definately installed the php console for chrome, I then tested the php console on http://php-console.com/instance/examples/#debug_vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to print out JSON from PHP

```
echo '<pre>';
    echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '</pre>';
```

**EDIT**

maybe you have a previous echo somewhere in your code

remove all your prints/echo/var_dump and try this code:

```
ob_end_clean();

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$json = json_encode($total);        
echo $json;
```

Comment: Thank-you. I've tried that, but doesn't seem to work. I've put the code I tried above.

Comment: i can see you left `exit;` statement before printing out the `$response`. Try to remove it

Comment: thanks, I removed  `exit;` & that doesn't seem to help

Comment: @mattnewbie sorry, you have to do `echo json_encode($total, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` since `$response` is not set yet.

Comment: Thanks, but it won't let me install the plugin with those changes. On the install page 'Cannot modify header information ` . It does say 'null' though as well!

Answer (score 1):

Use `var_dump($response)`, it gives better output when the value is an empty value like `null` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($response);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. I'd really appreciate it if you would look at my update 4 (above)

Comment: What does it output? Null?